# Not redeclarable variable PHP

Tags: php, variables

Is there any way to make an variable not redeclarable in PHP?
I mean if I set `$a = 2;` and then `$a = 3` the value of variable $a should still be "2".

Comment: no not a variable, but you can take a look at constant define('a',2) eg

Comment: A "not-redeclarable" variable is called a [constant](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php)

Comment: You could declare it as a constant const CONSTANT = 'constant value';

Comment: Why the downvotes? OP might not know the right terminology, but this is a legit question (as proven by the answers).

Comment: thanks, I didn't know that constants cannot be redeclared using define function once again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> You can use [define](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php) for declaring constant :

```
define('MY_VALUE','2');

echo MY_VALUE;//will always gives output 2
```

> OR

```
echo constant("MY_VALUE");//give same output as above
```

Comment: Convention says to give your constants all uppercase names.